# Как перейти из активити в активити

Tags: android

Что нужно написать, чтобы при выполнении некоторого условия, у меня из текущего активити переходило в другое, без нажатия кнопок?

Comment: Какого условия, где оно находится ? От чего зависит ?

Comment: Чтобы запустить актиивти надо вызвать `context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ActivityClass.class))`. Где это вызывать - в общем не важно. Можно по клику, можно как угодно ещё.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да, спасибо, это мне и надо было.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы перейти из одной активности в другую как уже писал [@ЮрийСПБ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%B1) нужно сделать так:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NextActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

но вам нужно чтобы переход осуществлялся при выполнении определенного условия, тогда вы в функции `onCreate()` должны указать это условие:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(ваше_условие){
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NextActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }else{
      //другое действие
    }
}
```

как-то так.

Comment: Спасибо, это то что надо было.

Comment: Если Вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку :)